# How to route traffic from localhost:8080 to localhost:8080/myapp

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I am having multiple application inside tomcat/webapps dir and all are running, they are accessible using below url:

1. **myapp1**: *localhost:8080/myapp1*
2. **myapp2**: *localhost:8080/myapp2*

i want to change the redirection for **myapp1** only. like if i put url *localhost:8080* it should redirect to *localhost:8080/myapp1* only.

However if i put url *localhost:8080/myapp2* then it should call the **myapp2**.

Please help me to solve this situation, I am new in this field and currently using Ubuntu16.04 and tomcat8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the below tag in server.xml

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

To below

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/myapp1"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

For more about configuration, you can learn from below URL
[https://www.udemy.com/apache-tomcat-for-beginners-and-advanced/?couponCode=TCSTACKPROMO]